# Select a range from a variable with multiple addresses

Tags: excel, vba

I got the solution from another thread to create a range of filtered rows:

```
Dim filterRange
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SCOPE").Range("A2").CurrentRegion
   filterRange = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlVisible).Address
End With
```

Now I want to select this range and copy its value into another sheet like this:

```
Range(filterRange).Select
```

But I do not understand why this is not working. Can someone explain it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must declare `filterRange As Range` then `Set filterRange` to get it working

Comment: No need to `.Select`! Copy `xlVisibleCells`. There are **plenty** of solutions on this site on how to do **exactly** what you are trying to do

Comment: Are you on `SCOPE Sheet` when trying to select that range? If not, the code will throw an error. You will need to activate the `SCOPE Sheet` first.

Comment: @Damian I have tried this before and it is not working. The Debugger says " Object is missing"

Comment: Sorry, forgot to tell you, you won't need the .address part just  `Set filterRange = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlVisible)` 
Butr as @urdearboy said, you should try to not use `Select` cause it may cause troubles.

Comment: @Damian - setting `filterRange` would not work, because the OP is using `filterRange` as a `String` variable in `Range(filterRange).Select`.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work only, when there is nothing written in `A3`.

Thus this part here `.Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)` returns an error, because it actually is evaluated to `.Resize(1 - 1)` and `0` is an invalid argument for the Range.Resize Property.

- [Range.Resize Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize)
- [CurrentRegion Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion)

---

Some way to go around this is:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim filterRange As String

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SCOPE").Range("A2").CurrentRegion
        If .Cells.Count <> 1 Then
           filterRange = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlVisible).Address
        Else
           filterRange = .Address
        End If
    End With

    Range(filterRange).Select

End Sub
```

However, this makes the code look a bit ugly, because it is using `.Select` and is passing the variable in `Range()` as a string from `.Address`. (But if you do not have prejudices and it is Friday in your time-zone - the go for it!)

- [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Okay, I get your point but this code will select all cells, not only the column "A". Further it only copies the cells displayed on the screen, not the ones underneath it.

Comment: @flubix - well, your question is literally *But I do not understand why this is not working*. Concerning the "all cells part", the `CurrentRegion` is the range, which is selected, if you select a given range and press Ctrl+A in Excel. If there are no cells in column B, then it would select only those in column A. Probably you need to define the range, using first and last cell - this is the most robust method.